# How to show a post as an element but remove the post from url

Tags: wordpress

I am building a website with Wordpress. I have created 3 posts and then I have created a category called "Testimonials" and now the posts are belong to Testimonials category.

In home page I have section for Testimonials. I show the Testimonials. every thing is good so far.

But the problem is: I don't want to have URL access for these posts and category...

I have set the posts to private it hides the posts from URL but then it also hides them in Testimonials section on home page.

Is there any way I can hide the URL to public without effecting the Testimonials section in home page?

Comment: Maybe on creation inject those posts in to a new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider creating a "custom post type" for your Testimonials. It's more appropriate than using the default Posts type, and you have the option, when setting it up, to exclude the new post type from the frontend.

Check out these posts:

WordPress docs on custom post types: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

How to hide custom post types from the frontend: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74468/how-to-set-a-custom-post-type-to-not-show-up-on-the-front-end

It's also nice to log into your backend admin screen and see a specific "Testimonials" menu item, rather than relying on blog posts with a specific category - much more of a CMS approach.

In fact, here is a tutorial on how to do exactly that. You can modify the code to do what you need it to do: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-client-testimonials-with-custom-post-types--wp-30263

Comment: Thank you @raffjones. I have already done it. This CPT is not going to be used for Testimonials only but other types of layouts like Sliders, FAQ and etc